# Python: Read multiple meta tag contents with the same property with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, metadata

Currently I'm pretty new with python and so I'm trying some things with BeautifulSoup.

My Problem is:
I want to read the video tags of a youtube video over python.
ex.

```
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="Official">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="Trailer"> 
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="Movie">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="Clip">
```

with:

```
yturl = soup.find("meta", {"property":"og:video:tag"})['content']
```

I can read just the first tag

and with:

```
yttag = soup.findAll("meta", {"property":"og:video:tag"})
```

everything after "og:video:tag" is listed and I just want the content.
Is there any possibility to use BeautifulSoup that I can read multiple meta tag contents with the same name/property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> html = '''
... <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Official">
... <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Trailer"> 
... <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Movie">
... <meta property="og:video:tag" content="Clip">
... '''
>>> 
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> [tag['content'] for tag in soup.findAll("meta", {"property":"og:video:tag"})]
['Official', 'Trailer', 'Movie', 'Clip']
# maps Tag elements to their content attributes
```